# Branch.io deeplink app is not opening after first click

Tags: ios, branch.io

I implement the Branch.io's deeplink .However the problem is when i share the link users can first click the link and it opens the app , everything is ok  but after you close the app and click the same link again it redirects you to App Store and another interesting issue is when you open the app by yourself it acts like you click the link which directs you to the target . If you do this try like 10 times , every time(10 times) you open the app by yourself it directs you just like you click the link in the same order that you click

Steps i am taking :

- Open Facebook From Safari
- Click the link from message that i recieve from friend
- Facebook directs me to app (Everything is fine)
- I click home button and terminate the app
- I go back to safari , safari reopens due to safari app coming from background to foreground so that it reopens the last page which is the deeplink
- This time safari directs me to App Store
- Since then any other my app's deeplink that i tap from WhatsApp , Facebook , Twitter etc. just goes to App Store

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: I think I understand part of the problem you're having, but I am afraid I can't quite follow the whole message. Could you edit your question to include some additional details, such as the steps you are using to test this?

Comment: @AlexBauer i added my test steps

Comment: to clarify, you are using the Facebook mobile website and _not_ the native iOS Facebook app? I have followed the steps above and am not seeing the same behavior. Is it possible you accidentally [disabled Universal Links](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/universal-app-links/support/ios/#universal-links-can-be-disabled-unfortunately)? If not, could you record a video of you performing the steps on your device?

Comment: @AlexBauer I am facing the same issue. can you please help me? I have setup everything in code and on Link Settings. I am testing it in test app.